# is_rtl returns false while it should return true

Tags: plugins, theme-development

I have two cases for `is_rtl`, one doesn't work the other does, but don't know why.

> Case1: doesn't work

i define a variable to hold a value depending on `is_rtl`, then `var_dump` it within the `admin_footer` hook, then the result becomes LTR

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Test
*/

class A{
    public function __construct(){
        $option_name = is_rtl() ? 'RTL ': 'LTR ';
        add_action('admin_footer', function() use($option_name){
            echo '<pre dir=ltr>';
              var_dump($option_name);
            echo '</pre><br>';
        });

    }
}


$a = new A();
```

> Case2: works

I define the variable inside the callable hooked to `admin_footer`, so the result becomes RTL

```
    <?php
/*
Plugin Name: Test
*/

class A{
    public function __construct(){

        add_action('admin_footer', function(){
            $option_name = is_rtl() ? 'RTL ': 'LTR ';
            echo '<pre dir=ltr>';
              var_dump($option_name);
            echo '</pre><br>';
        });

    }
}


$a = new A();
```

So why this happens because i need to load options depending on the page direction, but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1 - `is_rtl()` is not working because it has been called directly. To use such contditional tags in WordPress, query should already be run. So such function should be used inside the function hooked to appropriate hook. Since it is called directly, its value will be always false.

See https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/#where-to-use-conditional-tags

Case 2 - It is working because you can using this tag inside the function hooked to `admin_footer`. So, `is_rtl()` will give you appropriate value.

So, if `admin_footer` is not working for you then, you need to check which hook is appropriate for you and use `is_rtl()` inside the function hooked properly.

Comment: thank you for this explanation, but how i can achieve such funtionality without is_rtl.. because i need to load options according to page direction